# What does "binary identical" mean?

Tags: sql-server

In the context of SQL Server for embedded systems.

I read the following blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows-embedded/archive/2014/04/01/microsoft-sql-server-2014-for-embedded-systems-build-your-foundation-for-better-data-analytics-and-operational-intelligence-in-next-generation-intelligent-systems.aspx

In my opinion, there have to be some differences - because otherwise there wouldn't be a version especially for embedded systems...?

Thank you ;)

Comment: I would imagine it means that the code base is exactly the same, except perhaps for the API.  This question might be more appropriately asked to someone at Microsoft.

Comment: Question concerns software only existing in April fools joke.

Comment: i don't know if this is a joke. it is the same on the official product web site http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/microsoft-sql-server-2014-for-embedded-systems.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's an April Fools joke. To me the joke is the hollow and enterprisey language. They are not really saying anything in the entire post.

The post says the truth: SQL Server Enterprise is available for embedded devices. Just use the normal binaries and pay 7000$ per embedded CPU core :)